# How do the various magic paths compare in terms of benefits to early expansion?

Tags: dominions-6

One thing that I've struggled wrapping my head around as far as spells go is how to judge whether mages can contribute to expansion, going as far as making tables for useful spells in the first 2 levels of any school, i.e. Alt/Evo/Etc.

Some spells have an obvious impact, such as Earth Meld and Web vs standard human independents, and Summon Animals for a huge pile of boars and deer and whatever else to soak up the brunt of clash with Barbarians, the imps from Blood Magic are a very valuable distraction with flight and high defense for the cost of 1 blood slave. Other spells don't quite have the same impact; Death-1 combat spells in Conjuration for example are absolutely atrocious, generating around 5 crappy units per mage per battle whose main contribution is soaking up 1-2 attacks, and Earth-1 Con-1 grubs have very low armor and die way too fast (though their size does let them block a lot of tramplers and offer umbrellas to size-3 units, though whether that's valuable is arguable given the cost)

The question is thus, at a glance, how can one judge based on the starting research levels, and depending on available paths, whether ones mages can contribute to fighting independents or whether they should stay home and research something that's actually of use and have them come online later when they've had the opportunity to research level 2 in some other research category?

P.S. this mostly concerns generic spells and not nation/age-specific strategies, and if necessary, restricted to early ages and above ground (so cavalry, barbarians, other notables) but hopefully also underground (bekrydes, cynos, troglodytes)

Answer (score 1):

In general the benefits are the same - none.

Sending your mages to help with expansion against indies is not desireable, your mages have more important duties in getting your research up, searching for sites or constructing labs. Sending them off to do minorly helpful things you can do just fine without them is just to expensive.

Heavy Cavalry is best encountered with a few cheap, sacrificial lance catchers, Barbs are handled well by generic light infantry, elephants walk into a blob and die.

If you do want to use mages to aid with your expansion its the usual process. Do you have anything that makes your troops better? (Barkskin, Body ethereal) Do you have anything that removes the enemies strength? (Web or Earth Meld against cavalry, Evocations against Barbarians)